# How to read text written on a image?

Tags: parsing, image, ocr

I need to parse some scanned documents to textual data. Is it possible to parse text written on a image using some software.

If yes , please recommend any such online utility or software.

Comment: What language/tools/platform are you using?

Comment: i used acrobat professional 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe some OCR software would help?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition