# Programmatically reading text from an image

Tags: .net, image-processing, ocr

My question is similar to [this one 842986/how-to-read-text-written-on-a-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842986/how-to-read-text-written-on-a-image), except I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically.

**Essentially, does anyone know of a good, and simple, .NET compatible library, that is able to take in, say, a bitmap object or image object, and give me back any text on that image?**

cheers

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=.net%20ocr%20library&meta=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for a technology called "OCR" which stands for Optical Character Recognition. There are tons of apps out there that do this including several with a programming SDK.

For example: http://www.simpleocr.com/Info.asp