# How to read text written on an image android

Tags: java, android

I have a picture with text on it at different places and i want to read this text and show this in log as well. Can somebody share some useful information about how to do it in android application?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is part of the image, you will need to use an OCR package.

Tesseract is an open-source OCR with a port for android (see https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two).

SO posts:

[How to read text written on a image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842986/how-to-read-text-written-on-a-image)

[Is there any free OCR library for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106202/android-ocr)

Comment: hey, thanks for guidance i take ur advice and get in touch later

Answer (score -1):

Its So Simple.Take a Relative Layout and Put ImageView and a TextView inside it.
Take a look at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242951/android-text-over-image)

Comment: It seems that he needs OCR

Comment: yeah i also think it needs OCR to work. i'll let u know after i have done my test.